# In ASP.NET WebForms, cannot display all the treenodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, webforms

I'm new at C# and ASP.NET thing and I've got this task, which requires to display `TreeView` (parent-child) for all the elements in a database.

I've written this code in Default.aspx.cs and it does show roots (first parents) but I can't get any children. Could you help me out with that?
Thanks in advance.

The code follows:

```
namespace HierarchyApp
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Populate_List();
            }
        }

        private void Populate_List()
        {
            List<Hierarchy_Table> All_Items = new List<Hierarchy_Table>();
            using (Hierarchy_DBEntities dc = new Hierarchy_DBEntities())
            {
                All_Items = dc.Hierarchy_Table.ToList();
            }
            CreateHierarchy(0, null, All_Items);
        }

        private void CreateHierarchy(int Parent_ID, TreeNode Parent, List<Hierarchy_Table> database_source)
        {
            List<Hierarchy_Table> new_database_source = database_source.Where(x => x.PARENT_ID.Equals(Parent_ID)).ToList();
            foreach (var item in new_database_source)
            {
                TreeNode newItem = new TreeNode(item.NAME, item.ID.ToString());
                if (Parent == null)
                {
                    Hierarchy_Menu.Nodes.Add(newItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    {
                        Parent.ChildNodes.Add(newItem);
                    }
                    CreateHierarchy(item.ID, newItem, database_source);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your `CreateHierarchy` method. 
This line `List<Hierarchy_Table> new_database_source = database_source.Where(x => x.PARENT_ID.Equals(Parent_ID)).ToList();` doesn't look quite right to me. What you really should be looking at is the ID value of your current parent node.

Below is the updated code sample

```
private void CreateHierarchy(int Parent_ID, TreeNode Parent, List<Hierarchy_Table> database_source)
        {
            List<Hierarchy_Table> new_database_source = database_source.Where(x => Parent == null ? x.PARENT_ID == 0 : x.PARENT_ID.Equals(int.Parse(Parent.Value))).ToList();
            foreach (var item in new_database_source)
            {
                TreeNode newItem = new TreeNode(item.NAME, item.ID.ToString());
                if (Parent == null)
                {
                    Hierarchy_Menu.Nodes.Add(newItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    Parent.ChildNodes.Add(newItem);
                }
                CreateHierarchy(item.ID, newItem, database_source);
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps